# Terminal dynamic print urls in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gnome-terminal

I have a file containing urls (google.com, microsoft.com, etc). I want to print one url, then clear previous line from it. again write another url above. Code sample is below:

```
import sys
with open('url.txt') as u:
    for line in u:
          line=line.strip()
          print(line, end="\r")
          #also tried
          sys.stdout.write("\r{0}".format(line))
          sys.stdout.flush()
```

above code doesn't delete all previous chars. 
Example: "google.com" after "microsoft.com" will print as "google.com.com".
Anybody can tell me how to delete previous line completely?

Comment: If you are using code to write to a file, then this is not that code. At no point in the above snippet do you do anything but read from the file "url.txt" and send text to stdout (via both print and sys.stdout.write/flush). If you are piping the output of this to a file or something similar, you should include what you are putting in the terminal as well as the python code you are using.

Comment: @Evan Thanks for your fast response. I just want to check the validity of the url and simply print those url in terminal if it's valid.

Comment: @Evan Can you please tell me why this code not remove previous line if new line is smaller then previous line.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. In your original question you say "I want to print one url and delete that url and write another url above it", which seems to suggest you want to edit a file, but now you say you want to "check the validity of the url and simply print those url in terminal if it's valid". You should edit your question to make it clear what you want to accomplish. What do you mean by "delete"? What do you mean by "Valid"?

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i'm extreamly sorry I am not talking about file just terminal print.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So what do you mean by "valid"?

Comment: there is url contain ...google.com some other char just remove .... from then url.
Can you please tell me why above code not delete previous line if new line is smaller then previous line.

Comment: A carriage return in a terminal accomplishes exactly what a carriage return did on a typewriter. It returns the carriage to the beginning of the line, but all the text is still there. Clearing the line is a separate action, and is done by printing the escape sequence "\033[K"

Comment: This still won't accomplish whatever it is you are trying to do (still unclear), since the end result is you printing the same line twice, just clearing the input and rewriting it the second time with sys.stdout.write("\r\033[K{0}".format(line))

Comment: Even if you remove the first print, you will just end up quickly writing and clearing each line in the file until you are left with the last line in the file. What is the goal of this script? You mentioned checking if a url was "valid". What do you mean by this?

Comment: \033[K solve my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import sys
import time
with open('url.txt') as u:
  lastline = ""
  for count, line in enumerate(u.readlines()):
    if count != 0:  # do not delay on first item outputted
      time.sleep(4)  # 4 sec delay so user can read before next text appears
    line = str(line).strip("\n")
    print(' ' * (len(lastline) + 1), end='\r')  # clear last line
    print(line, end='\r')
    lastline = line
```

Tested on windows 10

Though, the cursor will be blinking at the start. To fix this, you can install the cursor module by `pip install cursor` and then use this slightly modified code:

```py
import sys
import time
import cursor
with open('url.txt') as u:
  lastline = ""
  for count, line in enumerate(u.readlines()):
    if count != 0:  # do not delay on first item outputted
      time.sleep(4)  # 4 sec delay so user can read before next text appears
    line = str(line).strip("\n")
    print(' ' * (len(lastline) + 1), end='\r')  # clear last line
    print(line, end='\r')
    lastline = line
    cursor.hide()
cursor.show()
```

Comment: I think your ans is much more similar to my question. This code works perfectly if urls are smaller to larger size. I mean 1.com 10.com 100.com but if you have larger to smaller size it will give some extra output from previous url. after microsoft.com google.com will become google.com.com.

Comment: That seems strange, ill test it some more

Comment: @AnirbanSingha Ok, I editied it and it works fine now. My bad

Comment: sys.stdout.write("\r033[K{0}".format(line) will be best. what do you think about it.